# golang fork exec error - gobuffalo

Tags: go

I am new to go and trying to create some basic gobuffalo apps but I keep encountering `fork/exec` errors such as

`ERRO[0000] Error: fork/exec /usr/local/bin/buffalo: exec format error`

My buffalo app is currently in the directory:

`~/projects/golang/src/github.com/buffalo_experiments/coke`

I tried renaming the `buffalo_experiments` folder to match my os usr which is `clementoh` but it didn't do any good.

Could someone please explain to me what's going on? I think because of this error... the migration files are not being generated when I run:

`buffalo g resource users name email bio:nulls.Text`

**Full stdout**

```
      create  actions/users.go
      create  actions/users_test.go
      create  locales/users.en-us.yaml
      create  templates/users/_form.html
      create  templates/users/edit.html
      create  templates/users/index.html
      create  templates/users/new.html
      create  templates/users/show.html
         run  buffalo db g model user name email bio:nulls.Text
         run  goimports -w actions/actions_test.go actions/app.go actions/home.go actions/home_test.go actions/render.go actions/users.go actions/users_test.go grifts/db.go grifts/init.go main.go models/models.go models/models_test.go
Usage:
  buffalo generate resource [name] [flags]

Aliases:
  resource, r

Examples:
$ buffalo g resource users
Generates:

- actions/users.go
- actions/users_test.go
- models/user.go
- models/user_test.go
- migrations/2016020216301234_create_users.up.fizz
- migrations/2016020216301234_create_users.down.fizz

$ buffalo g resource users --skip-migration
Generates:

- actions/users.go
- actions/users_test.go
- models/user.go
- models/user_test.go

$ buffalo g resource users --skip-model
Generates:

- actions/users.go
- actions/users_test.go

$ buffalo g resource users --use-model users
Generates:

- actions/users.go
- actions/users_test.go

Flags:
  -h, --help               help for resource
  -n, --name string        allows to define a different model name for the resource being generated.
  -s, --skip-migration     tells resource generator not-to add model migration
      --skip-model         tells resource generator not to generate model nor migrations
      --skip-templates     tells resource generator not to generate templates for the resource
      --use-model string   tells resource generator to reference an existing model in generated code

ERRO[0000] Error: fork/exec /usr/local/bin/buffalo: exec format error
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue:) 
you are may using the wrong buffalo binary `/usr/local/bin/buffalo`.
It should be the binary which is located in your $GOPATH. 
For Example: `$GOPATH/bin/buffalo`